# Sending failed: Http failure during parsing for https://

Tags: javascript, php, angular, phpmailer

I am trying to send form data to an email account with Angular 12 and PHPMailer. Every time I send the data I get this error in console: "Http failure during parsing for https://....". I think it has to be something with my Angular service. For example, Do I have to set the response type to text? and, how do I do it? or it may be something else?

This is my Angular service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MycontactService {

  apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  emailUrl = environment.emailUrl;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
      return of(result as T);
    }
  }


  sendMessage(landingForm:any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.emailUrl}`, landingForm, httpOptions).pipe(
        tap(
            message => console.log(message)
        ),
        catchError(this.handleError('Sending', []))
    );
  }


 
}
```

my PHPmailer file

```
<?php

require 'includes/PHPMailer.php';
require 'includes/SMTP.php';
require 'includes/Exception.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

if(isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['mensaje'])){
    
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje']; 

} 
// $opciones = $request->opciones;
// $nombre = $request->nombre;
// $email = $request->email;
// $empresa = $request->empresa;
// $telefono = $request->telefono;
// $empleados = $request->empleados;
// $pais = $request->pais;
// $mensaje = $request->mensaje; 

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);




try{
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = false;

    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                  
    $mail->Username   = 'kanazawa8213@gmail.com';

    $mail->Password   = '*******';                             
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;           
    $mail->Port       = 587;  

   

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('kanazawa8213@gmail.com', 'Ptree');
    $mail->addAddress('kanazawa8213@gmail.com');     


    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = 'Nuevo mensaje desde Ptree site';

    $mail->Body = "Este es un mensaje desde Ptree site:\n\n".
        " Nombre: " .$_POST['nombre'].
        "\n\n Email: " .$_POST['email'].
        "\n\n Mensaje: " .$_POST['mensaje'];


        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';

}
    // if($mail->send()){
    //     echo 'Message has been sent';
    // }else{
    //     echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    //     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    // }

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}


?>
```

Also, I got this response in my Web console:

[image: Web Console response]

Comment: This is very similar to your previous question. You've still got this line: `require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';` which points to a file that should not exist. What we really need to see is what is in the response that your JS is failing to parse, which will be visible in your web inspector, as I mentioned last time. Please add that to your question.

Comment: Hello Synchro, I have added my web console from Firefox. I hope this will bring some light here, ja!. Also, I will delete the PHPMailerAutoload.php

Comment: That's the error message, but it's not showing the actual content of what was returned. Look at the raw response in the network tab rather than at the error it causes.

Comment: Hello Synchro!, I found what I needed to do. I was getting a JSON in my response, so I had to use json_decode function in my PHP file to parse my data correctly. But another issue is that the mails are falling in the Spam folder, Is there any way in PHPMailer to prevent this?

Comment: If mails are sent properly, what's the exact problem here?  Have you checked those message? Usually, they contain debugging information about the spam filtering in their header lines

Comment: As always, start by [reading the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Improving-delivery-rates,-avoiding-spam-filters).

Comment: Thanks Synchro! There is something with the spf that needs to be configured.